# Trying to subset based on top frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['fruit'] = ['apple','pear','banana','banana','pear','banana','apple','apple','pear','apple','apple','apple']
df['price'] = [2,1,3,3,1,3.3,1.8,1.8,1,1.6,1.6,1.6]
df['date_buy'] = ['01/01/2005','01/01/2005','01/01/2005','01/01/2005','01/02/2005','01/02/2005','01/02/2005','01/02/2005','01/03/2005','01/03/2005','01/03/2005','01/03/2005']
df.date_buy = df.date_buy.astype('datetime64')
df.set_index('date_buy', inplace = True)

pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index=['date_buy'],columns = ['fruit'], values = ['price'], aggfunc = sum).\
fillna(0).resample('D', level=0).sum()

            price
fruit       apple   banana  pear
date_buy            
2005-01-01  2.0     6.0     1.0
2005-01-02  3.6     3.3     1.0
2005-01-03  4.8     0.0     1.0
```

I want to subset some columns on pivot_df, the bottom two of the sum of price. In this case should be pear (sums 3) and banana (sums 9.3)

```
            price
fruit       banana  pear
date_buy            
2005-01-01  6.0     1.0
2005-01-02  3.3     1.0
2005-01-03  0.0     1.0
```

Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try [nsmallest](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html#pandas-series-nsmallest):

```
filtered = pivot_df[pivot_df.sum().nsmallest(2).index]
```

`filtered`:

```
           price       
fruit       pear banana
date_buy               
2005-01-01   1.0    6.0
2005-01-02   1.0    3.3
2005-01-03   1.0    0.0
```

Comment: And it can use nlargest too, thank you @Henry Ecker, I appreciate answers that makes me investigate more!